# How to make ip address configurable in web api to enable CORS?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am developing API's using Web API2. My front end application is hosted in the different server than where APIis hosted.

```
 [EnableCors(origins: "http://192.168.0.213", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

I want to make above IP address configurable. For example is there any option I can add a key with the value in web.config and access that IP address in Origins? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try implementing a custom cors policy provider https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: Thanks. I added public static string clientipaddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientipaddress"];   var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(clientipaddress, "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors); is this is the right way?

Comment: That would work, but you would be enabling cors globally on all controllers.

Comment: Yes. I do not have issues. I have fixed controllers